# Map image area on image with turn.js

Tags: javascript, html, css

`[enter code here][1]`I'm trying to map an area on an image. 
This image is part of a `turn.js` code. 
It's a magazine flip, but now I want a clickable area on the image.
I can't figure out how to, I feel like the JS code is overwriting the clickable area.
Can somebody help me out? Would be GREAT.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>turn.js</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body background="BOOKLETS/background.jpg" >
  <div id="magazine">
    <div>
      <span class="text">
        <img class="img-fluid" src=BOOKLETS/test1.jpg>
      </span>
    </div>

    <div>
      <span class="text">
        <a herf="www.youtube.com">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="BOOKLETS/test2.jpg" usemap="#image-map">
            <map name="image-map">
              <area href="www.youtube.com" coords="1430,1440,931,816"  shape="rect">
            </map>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>

    <div>
      <span class="text">
        <img class="img-fluid" src=BOOKLETS/test3.jpeg>
      </span>
    </div>

    <div>
      <span class="text">
        <img class="img-fluid" src=BOOKLETS/test4.jpg>
      </span>
    </div>    
  </div>

  <script  src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please post the content of the file `js/index.js`

Comment: Then you need to post the relevant code. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: The index.js is to big but it's basically this code https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/

Comment: I understand that you can't be bothered to post the relevant code, but you need to help us help you. Kindly recreate your problem in a website like [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) so people would be more keen on helping you.

Comment: It took me a while !  https://jsfiddle.net/ninarosa/qxpa91d8/

Comment: The clickable area does exist in your fiddle at the top right and at the top left when you flip the page. What is the problem?

Comment: I want to make specific elements on the image clickable. I thought to map an area on the image (flip page) so you could click on it. But it doesn't work